# Convert travel times from list to UTC and back to local time in vb

Tags: vb.net

```
Private Airports As String() = {"MIA", "JFK", "HNL", "LAX", "DFW"}
    Private utcOffsets As Integer() = {-4, -4, -10, -7, -5}
    Private travelTimes As Double(,) = {{0, 3, 12, 8, 2.5}, _
      {3, 0, 14, 8.5, 3.5}, {12, 14, 0, 4.5, 8.5}, _
      {8, 8.5, 4.5, 0, 3.5}, {2.5, 3.5, 8.5, 3.5, 0}}                             
Private Sub FlightTime_Load() Handles MyBase.Load
    dtpDepartureDate.Value = Today
End Sub

Private Sub btnGo_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles     btnGo.Click

    Dim departWhen As DateTime = dtpDepartureDate.Value.Date
    Dim departTime As DateTime
    Dim departIndex = cboDepartFrom.SelectedIndex
    Dim arriveIndex = cboArriveAt.SelectedIndex

    If cboDepartFrom.SelectedIndex < 0 Then
        errProvider.SetError(cboDepartFrom, "Select Departing Airport")
        Return
    End If
    If cboArriveAt.SelectedIndex < 0 Then
        errProvider.SetError(DirectCast(cboArriveAt, Control), "Select Destination Airport.")
        Return
    End If

    If Date.TryParse(txtDepartTime.Text, departTime) = Nothing Then
        errProvider.SetError(txtDepartTime, "Departure time must be in form 00:00")
        Return
    End If
    '
    departWhen = departWhen.AddHours(departTime.Hour)
    departWhen = departWhen.AddMinutes(departTime.Minute)
    'converting departure date/time to UTC time
    departWhen = departWhen.AddHours(-utcOffsets(departIndex))

    txtArrivalDateTime.Text = (departWhen & "  " & "Travel time is")
End Sub
```

End Class
I have these lists and from a combo box a departing airport and a destination airport are selected along with a departing time picked from a DateTimePicker. In the final result I need to display the Arrival Date/Time and the total travel time such as "You arrive on 2/13/15 at 03:00, Total travel time is 10 hours."
Any suggestions on how to proceed from this point would be appreciated.

Comment: Hi and welcome. Have you tried any solutions?

Comment: Don't forget day light saving.

Comment: Here is what I have fond so far about utc offsets.                                        Dim localTime As DateTime = txtDepartTime.Text
 Dim utcTime As DateTime
 Dim utcOffsets As Integer = -5
 utcTime = localTime.Add(New TimeSpan(0, utcOffsets, 0, 0)) But I still don't know how to retrieve the user input from the list to start this process. I am a very inexperienced student of VB.NET